# Can I make something exactly the same as <input checked={this.state.foo === "foo"} /> with <button /> ? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a small problem. I've made a multi-step form for some kind of service but most of the fields(almost each one of them) are buttons. I want to pass a value to the state to make it pass through props to the end of the form. I did something similar in the previous project with `<input checked={} />` but the dots look so ugly and old. Here is my question: Is there any way I can do it with buttons or at least get rid of dots under inputs?

Function for changing state:

```js
handleChange = (e: any) => {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
  });
};
```

Small sample of code of button:

```js
<button
  className="choose_rank"
  name="selectMode"
  id="selectMode"
  value="conquest"
  // checked={values.selectMode === "conquest"}
  onClick={this.toggleConquest}
  onChange={handleChange}
  defaultValue={values.selectMode}
>
  {this.state.isConquest ? (
    <img src={conquestIconOn} alt="conquest_icon" />
  ) : (
    <img src={conquestIconOff} alt="conquest_icon" />
  )}
</button>
```

Comment: Are you using react-bootstrap? It has a very nice ToggleButton component. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/

Comment: @terrymorse No, sadly I dont use react-bootstrap :/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `button` element has not `checked` attribute like the `input` element. but here you have ReactJS, create your button component with your own props, then do what you want, pay attention to the below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import cn from 'classnames';

type ButtonProps = {
  checked: boolean,
  className: string,
  name: string,
  id: string,
  value: string,
  defaultValue: string,
  onClick: () => void,
  onChange: () => void,
};

const Button = ({
  checked,
  className,
  name,
  id,
  value,
  defaultValue,
  onClick,
  onChange,
  ...rest,
}: ButtonProps) => (
  <button
    className={cn(className, checked && "someClassName")}
    name={name}
    id={id}
    value={value}
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    onClick={onClick}
    onChange={onChange}
  />
);

export default Button;
```

Now you can use the above `Button` component instead of the `button` element and also, you can pass the `checked` prop as a boolean value to the component. the `className={cn(className, checked && "someClassName")}` is just a example of usage. I imported the `cn` function from the `classname` library to handle multi-classnameas and if the `checked` will be `true` the `someClassName` will be assigned to the button element and you can use any CSS for that. there is a lot of ways to use this boolean prop and it's up to you.

Comment: Ahh I see, I didnt have any experience with 'classname' library but ill check that for sure and tell you about my results! :D